# KDTree with periodic boundary conditions and pair distances in output

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, scipy, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I want to run a nearest neighbour search over >10k points that lie within a periodic box and returns me the distances of these points together with their indices.

So far I tried `sklearn.neighbors.KDTree(positions).query_radius(positions, r=maximum_distance,return_distance=True)` which returns me the nearest neighbour distances within a max. radius, however it does not work for periodic boundary condition (PBC). Another method I have explored is `scipy.spatial.cKDTree(positions, boxsize=box_size).query_pairs(r=maximum_distance)` which works with PBC but does not return distances between pairs.

Would it be possible to extend  `sklearn.neighbors.KDTree` with the capability to handle PBC as `scipy.spatial.cKDTree`does?

Or

Would it be possible to extend `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` with the capability to return pair distances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

```
scipy.spatial.cKDTree().query()
```